# Delete elements of a list that appear in another list

Tags: list-manipulation

Basically I need to do a set substraction operation `A-B=C` between two lists.
For example, I have two lists `A` and `B`:

```
A = {{1,2,3,4},{3,4,3,4},{1,1,1,5},{1,2,1,2},{4,3,2,1}} 

B = {{1,2,1,2}, {1,2,3,4}}
```

and the result would be all the elements of `A` that do not appear in `B` and keeping the order of A:

```
C  = {{3,4,3,4},{1,1,1,5},{4,3,2,1}}
```

It is important to know that list B could be empty in some cases

I am also avoiding loops or recursion.
Thank you all <3.

Comment: Look up `Complement`. It does not retain the *order* in A.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 7):

As @Szabolcs said with no order:

```
Complement[A, B]
```

> {{1, 1, 1, 5}, {3, 4, 3, 4}, {4, 3, 2, 1}}

but to keep order you can try:

```
DeleteCases[A, Alternatives @@ B]
```

> {{3, 4, 3, 4}, {1, 1, 1, 5}, {4, 3, 2, 1}}

You might need too look up *levelspec* option for `DeleteCases` depending on a situation. Some other ways to keep order

```
Delete[A, Position[A, Alternatives @@ B]]

Select[A, ! MemberQ[B, #] &]
```

with perhaps a few more others.

Comment: What about if list B is empty?

Comment: @Gabriela did you check if these methods work with empty list?

Comment: @Gabriela, the nice thing about *Mathematica* is that as long as you know the function to use, questions on how it would behave for a particular case can be easily tried out by doing the experiments yourself.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov yeah it works :D It did not work at first but was a mistake of mine, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 3, 4}, {1, 1, 1, 5}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {4, 3, 2, 1}};

b = {{1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 4}};
```

Using `DeleteElements` and `UniqueElements` (both new in 13.1)

```
DeleteElements[a, b]
```

{{3, 4, 3, 4}, {1, 1, 1, 5}, {4, 3, 2, 1}}

```
First @ UniqueElements[{a, b}]
```

{{3, 4, 3, 4}, {1, 1, 1, 5}, {4, 3, 2, 1}}

"Both are much slower than `Complement`, but keep the sort order.